# Weird Common Lisp intersection behaviour

Tags: set, lisp, common-lisp, multiset

I'm trying to get the common elements of two lists. 
I've tried both the available intersection function and one I implemented myself, both giving the same weird result when trying to test them on lists like `(a a ... a)` and `(a b c d ... z)`.

Whenever the first list contains only the same element several times and the second list begins with that element the result is the first list.

For example: `(intersection '(2 2 2 2) '(2 2 2 3))` returns `(2 2 2 2)`

The intersection I implemented:

```
(defun presentp (a l)
  (cond ((null l) nil)
        ((and (atom (car l)) (equal a (car l))) t)
        ((not (atom (car l))) (presentp a (car l)))
        (t (presentp a (cdr l)))))

(defun intersectionp (a b)
  (cond ((not (and a b)) nil)
        ((presentp (car a) b) (append (list (car a)) (intersection (cdr a) b)))
        (t (intersection (cdr a) b))))
```

How can I get a good result on lists of that type? For example I want `(2 2 2)` from `(intersection '(2 2 2 2) '(2 2 2 3))`.

Comment: I'm using LispWorks and the INTERSECTION function is in the package COMMON-LISP so I'm asuming it's CLISP? [screenshot](http://puu.sh/8X5YV/270f631a67.png)

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a sort of think-o.  There's nothing the matter with the method returning `(2 2 2 2)` in this case.  (I was thinking `union` for some reason.  `cl:intersection` is supposed to return a list containing all the elements that are in the first and second lists.  If the first list only contains elements from the second, then the first list contains exactly those elements that appear in both, so it's not a bug to return the first list.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: In your first comment, you say that it returns `(2 2 3 2)` which I assume is a typo and you meant `(2 2 2 2)`

Comment: @alecutheman OK, I know you've already accepted an answer, but there is some interesting stuff going on here, and it's worth taking a look at what the spec mandates and permits, so I've added an answer about what's actually going on here.  Interestingly enough, `(intersection '(2 2 2 3) '(2 2 2 2))` in LispWorks does return `(2 2 2)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove matches from the `b` list.. When you found an 2 in `(2 2 2 3)` you should continue with `(2 2 3)` as `b`.

Also.. `(append (list x) result-list)` is the same as `(cons x result-list)` just with the same or fewer CPU cylces.

```
(defun intersection (a b)
  (cond ((not (and a b)) nil)
        ((presentp (car a) b)
         (cons (car a) 
               (intersection (cdr a) 
                             (remove (car a) b :count 1))))
        (t (intersection (cdr a) b))))
```

Comment: I understand my mistake and following your code it should work as expected, but it doesn't, it gives the same result :p

Comment: It should work but for some reason in breaks if the length of the initial list is 3 or greater: [example](http://puu.sh/8X4vc/801466edc3.png)

Comment: @alecutheman I belived i tested this but i must have copied an old version. The original code had a typo where the name was not the same as what was recursed. It's correct now :)

Comment: I missed the typo as well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

There's already an accepted answer, but I want to point out that the answer the implementation provides, where

```
(cl:intersection '(2 2 2 2) '(2 2 2 3))
;=> (2 2 2 2)
```

*is* correct.  It's important to recognize that the intersection, nintersection, etc., are intended for use with lists that are being treated as sets.  Conceptually, a set has no duplicate elements (for that you'd need a *multiset*), so the lists (2), (2 2), (2 2 2), etc., all represent the same set, {2}.

> ### [14.1.2.2 Lists as Sets](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/14_abb.htm)
>
> Lists are sometimes viewed as sets by considering their elements
>   unordered and by assuming there is no duplication of elements.
>
> ```
> adjoin         nset-difference    set-difference    union  
> intersection   nset-exclusive-or  set-exclusive-or         
> nintersection  nunion             subsetp
> ```
>
> **Figure 14-5. Some defined names related to sets.**

Now, that bit about "assuming there is no duplication of elements" actually means that you probably shouldn't be using the set functions with a list like (2 2 2 2), since there's obvious duplication of elements.  Even so, if you posit that lists like (2 2 2) and (2 2 2 2) represent the same *set*, you can see that `intersection` is actually giving you the correct *set* back.  I think that the specification actually mandates that the result will have three or four elements. From the HyperSpec entry on [intersection](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_isec_.htm):

> The intersection operation is described as follows. For all possible
>   ordered pairs consisting of one element from list-1 and one element
>   from list-2, :test or :test-not are used to determine whether they
>   satisfy the test. The first argument to the :test or :test-not
>   function is an element of list-1; the second argument is an element of
>   list-2. If :test or :test-not is not supplied, eql is used. It is an
>   error if :test and :test-not are supplied in the same function call. …
>
> For every pair that satifies the test, exactly one of the two elements
>   of the pair will be put in the result. No element from either list
>   appears in the result that does not satisfy the test for an element
>   from the other list. If one of the lists contains duplicate elements,
>   there may be duplication in the result.

So, in the case of `(2 2 2 2)` and `(2 2 2 3)`, there are 16 pairs to consider:

```
(2 2) (2 2) (2 2) (2 3) ; first element is first  2 from list-1, second elements are from list-2 
(2 2) (2 2) (2 2) (2 3) ; first element is second 2 from list-1, second elements are from list-2 
(2 2) (2 2) (2 2) (2 3) ; first element is third  2 from list-1, second elements are from list-2 
(2 2) (2 2) (2 2) (2 3) ; first element is fourth 2 from list-1, second elements are from list-2
```

Since "For every pair that satifies the test, *exactly one* of the two elements of the pair will be put in the result," it seems to me that you're going to end up with between 3 and 4 2's in the result, because you've got 12 pairs that satisfy the test, and you need to cover each row and column of those 12 pairs.  This hinges, I suppose, on the interpretation of "exactly one of the two elements of the pair will be put in the result".  In general though, if you have, e.g., lists-as-sets `(a1 a2)` and `(b1 b2 b3)` then you have the pairs:

```
(a1 b1) (a1 b2) (a1 b3)
(a2 b1) (a2 b2) (a2 b3)
```

I *think* that the spec should be read as saying that each `ai` and `bi` will be included at most once, and that you never include a given `ai` and `bi` based on the particular pair `(ai bi)`.  So, if from row one you were to select `(a1 b2)` and include `b2` in the result, then the remaining pairs that could contribute elements to the result are

```
(a1 b1) (a1 b3)
(a2 b1) (a2 b3)
```

if you had taken `a1` from `(a1 b2)`, then the remaining pairs would be

```
(a2 b1) (a2 b2) (a2 b3)
```

That is, when you include an element from one of the pairs, you've either removed a row or a column from the table of pairs that determine the possible results.  In the first case, you could still add two more elements to the result, but in the second, there could be three.

In fact, in LispWorks, if you reverse the order of the arguments, you'll get the 3 element version:

```
CL-USER 5 > (intersection '(2 2 2 3) '(2 2 2 2))
(2 2 2)
```

> There is no guarantee that the order of elements in the result will
>   reflect the ordering of the arguments in any particular way. The
>   result list may share cells with, or be eq to, either list-1 or list-2
>   if appropriate.

You didn't mention whether you're just getting an equivalent list back, or if you're actually getting list-1 back.  In Lispworks, it seems that you're actually getting the same list back, although that's not required:

```
CL-USER 2 > (let ((l1 '(2 2 2 2))
                  (l2 '(2 2 2 3)))
              (eq l1 (intersection l1 l2)))
T
```

Comment: That's interesting I guess but I can't see any purpose for such a function. I would expect commutativity from the intersection operation, at least to some extent, that is to say at least getting results that have the same elements even if in a different order.

Comment: You **do** have commutativity, though. Intersection &al. are for lists-as-sets. The same set is denoted by (2), (2 2), (2 2 2) and (2 2 2 2).

Answer (score 0):

Here is mine that works well. I used remove to remove duplicating symbols.

```
(defun my-intersection (x y)
   (cond ((or (null x) (null y)) nil)
     ((find (first x) y) (cons (first x)
                   (my-intersection (remove (first x) x) y)))
     (t (my-intersection (rest x) y))))
```